# Example about convergence that I don't understand

Tags: real-analysis

In the following example there is slight techniaclity  that I would would like to address so in the following example did they show that that sequence is Cauchy or did they show that sequence is convergent sequence according to how I read it they showed that the sequence given below is convergent.
Maybe I didn't make the question very clear I don't understand how did they show here that the sequence below is actually Cauchy ? 
 [image]

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is asked here. They did show that the sequence is Cauchy, but $\mathbb R$ is complete, so the sequence is convergent.

Comment: This is a "contraction" sequence, and any contraction sequence is Cauchy, and thus convergent in a Banach space (complete metric space).

Comment: I don't understand how did they show it is cauchy here I don't get that ?

Comment: @Dude a Cauchy sequence $a_n$ fulfills : if $n+p>n>N$ with $N$ large enough, then $|a_{n+p}-a_n|<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a positive number specified beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have shown that the sequences is convergent by showing that it is Cauchy.  In $\Bbb R$, being Cauchy is equivalent to being convergent.

Let $\epsilon>0$, since $b_n\to 0$, there is a $N$ such that $n\ge N\implies b_n<\epsilon/2.$  Now, the proof shows that for $m>n\ge N$, we have $|a_m-a_n|<2b_n<\epsilon$.  This is precisely, the Cauchy condition.

Comment: I don't understand how did they show that is cauchy ? They show that they approach each other since the limit is zero of $b_n$?

Comment: I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Happy to help out.